# Where can I find a translation for romanized (english texted) sanskrit into english?

Tags: english, translation, transliteration

I am trying to find a translator link to change romanized or english texted sanskrit (as in bollywood and other Indian songs and chants) into actual english so that I can understand what the song means in English.

For example I am trying to translate something like this: "aao huzoor tumko, sitaron mein le chaloo" into (actual english words like the, love, man, woman, etc)

Comment: If it's from Bollywood, it's not Sanskrit, at least not in a song. It's probly Hindi. Try the translator on that setting.

Comment: Sanskrit is an ancient language. It's not a Bollywood language.

Comment: Google Translate seems to recognize the language at least: [link for your example](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/aao%20huzoor%20tumko%2C%20sitaron%20mein%20le%20chaloo). (You can try both Hindi and Urdu to get slightly different translations.) Of course the quality of its translation is very poor, but you can get a general sense of what is being spoken about.

Answer (score 1):

The only web site I know that gives you a word-by-word translation is
https://hindustanisongs.com
It usually provides translations as literal as possible (not interpretative), and you can click on each word for the "morphological analysis" (case, gender, number, tense, etc.) and the dictionary form.